# How to fetch and display an array using PDO?

Tags: arrays, pdo, fetch

I understand there are MANY ways to do all of this, but trying to do it the best way.

I have created the db parameters, dns, dbh, sth, sql and generally quite happy with the result up to ... well ... the result part.

```
<?php

// db parameters
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "x";
$dbuser = "y";
$dbpass = "z";

// driver invocation (dsn is short for data source name)
$dsn = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname";

// create db object (dbh is short for database handle)
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass);

// execution of database query (sth is short for statement handle)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM a_aif_remaining";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
```

**NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT BELOW.... (A) or (B)**

*I just want to present a simple array of the data. One row from the table per line.*

**Option A**

```
echo $_POST['fieldname1'];
echo $_POST['fieldname2'];
echo $_POST['fieldname3'];
```

**Option B**

```
while ($rows = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row[fieldname1],'<br>';
    }
```

**AND I AM CONFIDENT WITH THE ENDING**

```
    $dbh = NULL;

?>
```

Any advise would be GREATLY appreciated.

### UPDATED CODE: (Produces nothing on the page)

```
<?php

    // db parameters
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "theaudit_db1";
    $dbuser = "theaudit_user";
    $dbpass = "audit1999";

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname"; // driver invocation (dsn is short for Data Source Name)

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass); // connect to new db object (dbh is short for Database Handle)
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // set the PDO error mode to enable exceptions
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); // set the PDO emulate prepares to false

    // execute query to database (sth is short for Statement Handle)
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM a_aif_remaining";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();

    $data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $dbh = NULL;
}

catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to intend to produce anything on the page. The word "array" has a special meaning in computer languages, it's a variable of complex type, contains other variables - so I took it. If you meant "array of strings on my page" - either use your B or `foreach` over `$data` variable from my code.

Comment: I mean like a CSV file basically... One sql result to show up on one row in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Though I can't get what's the connection between A anb B, I can answer the

> I just want to present a simple array of the data. One row from the table per line.

question.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM a_aif_remaining";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();
$data = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

where `$data` is a sought-for array.

Comment: I have tried what you suggest and it is not working. I've even wrapped it in an exception clause, but still not working.

Comment: the connection between A and B is that both are an associative array, no?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your updated code is simple - you arent echo'ing your data out. You need to add something like..

```
   foreach($data as $arKey=>$dataRow){
        foreach($dataRow as $arKey=>$rowField){
             echo $rowField.','; //concat with a ',' to give csv like output 
        }
        echo '<br>'; //to get to next line for each row (may want to trim the last ','
   }
```

I am also confused by the reference to $_POST. It is true both are associate arrays but that does not mean that the $_POST option is viable - the data would only be available in the $_POST if you put it there (eg $_POST = $data) which would be pointless. Or if you had posted the data from somewhere else. Neither seem to fit what you are asking so I would forget about the $_POST and just figure out how you access your multi dimensional $data array. There is endless tut's on this subject. Try using

```
    var_dump($data)
```

to see whats inside that should help you visualise what is going on.

NOTE: in option B you are not correctly concatenating or referencing your array it should be:

```
    while ($rows = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $rows[fieldname1].'<br>'; //$row doesnt exist its $rows and you use . to concat not ,
        }
```

Ah yes and probably better to use unset rather than setting $dbh to equal null

```
unset($dbh);
```